# What is the meaning of "[ |]+" in "awk -F '[ |]+'"?

Tags: awk

I know that the `-F` in `awk -F` stands for a following field separator.

But what does `'[ |]+'` mean?

Note the `blank` before the `|`.

I am also wondering, what does the `+` stand for?

Comment: You can read more about regular expressions at the [info page for the `regex` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field separator can be a regular expression, which is the case here. `[ |]` is a bracket expression that stands for "either a space or a pipe character"; `+` is a quantifier ("one or more"). Overall, this can be used to split lines like

```
field1|field2  field3||  field4
```

as pipe-separated, throwing away all the blanks around the pipe, i.e., the four fields would be `field1`, `field2`, `field3` and `field4`.

Answer (score 2):

Awk allows for the field separator to be a regular expression.

`[ |]+` is a regular expression which matches any non-empty sequence of space and pipe (`|`) characters.